# AttibuteError when trying to get personal_access_token when using python-gitlab library

Tags: gitlab, python-gitlab

I'm trying to perform a basic task of getting the logged in users GitLab personal access token using the python-gitlab library.  The documentation here is what I am using in the code below - https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/personal_access_tokens.html

But I get...

`token = gl.personal_access_tokens.get("self")`

AttributeError: 'PersonalAccessTokenManager' object has no attribute 'get'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of `python-gitlab`. You'll need to upgrade to at least v3.14.0, released in April 2023, where support for this `GET` endpoint was added.

https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/releases/tag/v3.14.0

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out, nejc!  For now I am stuck using python-gitlab 3.11.  Do you know if there is functionality available in this release to rotate a personal access token?  Thanks again for your help

Comment: The rotate token API was added in v4.4.0, so you'd also need to upgrade.

You can probably upgrade by installing it from pypi (either via pip or other python package manager) rather than using an OS-level package manager.

There are workarounds by using the lower-level methods like`Gitlab.http_get()` directly but ideally you just use more recent version.